# How to use React useContext with Formik FieldArray in multistep dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have been coding for 4 months, this is my first post and my first time using SandBox, feel free to roast me...
I am trying to make a complicated multistep, dynamic form where users can input information about cars. I am trying to use the React hook useContext because I figured it was the best way to pass around the data. I am also trying to make part of the form dynamic using Formik FieldArray, where a user could input multiple past owners of the car.
This is where I am stuck. Specifically on the "Previous Owner" section when trying to use FieldArray. The data gets set with useContext, but it freaks out when trying to add more than one previous owner. I think it's because it's not identifying each previous owner as an additional object. The TextField also loses focus after each character input.
I created a SandBox in order to see it visually plus the code. I also added the JSON values as it kinda helped me see whats going on.
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/car-manager-nepws7?file=/src/components/FormContext.jsx)
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is a complicated question. As another comment mentioned, you'll get better results asking one or more very specific questions in your post. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, particularly https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .